# Rewrite one domain to another with query string

Tags: regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have moved my site to another domain. I want to redirect the old domain to the new, and keep the query string. Below is just one of my attempts. The redirect works, but does not add the query string.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynewdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Example of what I would like to accomplish:

User visits:
`http://www.mydomain.com/blog`

They are redirected to:
`http://www.mynewdomain.com/blog`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Going to attempt to answer my own question!

I seems that the code above actually works, but only when the user explicitly types in the http:// before the domain. I changed the code to the following to support for `http://` and `www`. It seems to work correctly now.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynewdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now it allows for anything before the domain. If anyone sees an issue with this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: %{HTTP_HOST} does include sub-domains so the `www.` beforehand would have to be checked so you can do it. Such as `^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$`.. If you can check VirtualHost, then you can redirect through mod_alias from one host to the other as well.

Comment: @Chris, to append query string to redirected url. you will have to add QSA in flags.